# Version Control in Big Query

Tags: version-control, google-bigquery, view

I have a saved set of Big Query (BQ) views that I regularly use for my Analytics needs.  However it is very easy to overwrite or delete them as you manipulate them. Is there any BQ functionality to back them up without having to store them in a text file?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know if BigQuery has such built in functionality, but why not just use a VCS tool like Git?

Comment: can you clarify - what you mean by "manipulate them"?

Comment: As Tim suggested, you can basically just check in a bunch of `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...` statements to GitHub. There is no BigQuery-provided versioning system.